# Calculate the sum of $\:\frac{x}{5} + \:\frac{x}{11} + \:\frac{x}{17} .... + \:\frac{x}{p} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, harmonic-functions, harmonic-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

Let's say $x = 161$, and I want to calculate the sum of all :
$$\:\frac{x}{5} + \:\frac{x}{11} + \:\frac{x}{17} .... + \:\frac{x}{p} $$
$$(\text{pattern}  = \:\frac{x}{\left(6n-1\right)}\:) $$

but the limit  $p = floor(\:\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{6}) = 2, $ since max perfect square bellow $161$ from the list ($5^2, 11^2, 17^2$) is $11^2$

If I'm correct this is the correct formula:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{p}\:\frac{x}{\left(6n-1\right)}\:$$
Where  $$p=\left\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{6}\right\rfloor$$

Now, how can I calculate it ? ( accurate or approximations) :

I tried the function bellow, and it's very very accurate approximation, but this is for all fractions, $1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...$, in my example above I want to select only $5, 11, 17, ...$
$$xH(x) \approx x (\ln x+\gamma )-\frac{1}{12 x}+\frac{1}{2}$$
Where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma\approx 0.577215665$.

Comment: $p = floor(\:\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{6}) = 2$, (floor(2.2814) = 2), and max perfect square below $161$ only from the list $(5, 11, 17, ...)$

Comment: I've just edited the post, for more clarity !

Comment: If $x=161$ you want to add $x/5+x/11=\frac{16}{55}\,x$. If I got it right, may I know the reason why?

Comment: After some difficulties to eliminate the floor function I got using Mathematica $\sum _{n=1}^{\left\lfloor \frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)\right\rfloor } \frac{x}{6 n-1}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{5}-\frac{2907}{5000 x}-\frac{63}{125 \sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{12} x (\ln (x)-1.80206)+\frac{13}{100}$. Hope this helps.

Comment: using $x=161$ as in your example the exact value is $46+\frac{46}{55}$ while the approximated value is $46.62$. The exact value of the sum is $\frac{1}{6} \left(x \psi \left(\left\lfloor \frac{1}{6} \left(\sqrt{x}+1\right)\right\rfloor +\frac{5}{6}\right)-x \psi \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\right)$, where $\psi(x)$ is the digamma special function.

Comment: Can I know where did you get : $(2907/5000,  63/125, 1.80206, 13/100)$ from ?

Comment: It is Taylor polynomial at $x=+\infty$ computed by Mathematica. The main problem was using taylor with the floor function, so I had to estimate $\lfloor x\rfloor$ as $x$ less something. It is a compromise, but it works quite well. Otherwise you can use the exact formula with the $\psi$ function

Comment: $\int^0_{-100} \frac{1}{6n-1}dn=-1.066$ due to Wolfram .